# Imagem de banco de dados exibida em primefaces não aparece

Tags: mysql, jsf, primefaces, imagem

Estou implementando uma página em que preciso exibir um datagrid com os valores de uma tabela no banco de dados. Cada linha da tabela possui uma imagem do tipo blob.

Porém ao tentar exibir a imagem com o primefaces pela tag : , ela não aparece.

abaixo tem a parte do código da entidade em que tem a propriedade da imagem e a função que a coloca no formato DefaultStreamedContent que é suportada pela tag do primefaces.

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] imagem;

public Projetista() {

}

public StreamedContent mostrarImagemDeByte(){
    InputStream in = null;
    StreamedContent sc;
    if(this.imagem != null){
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.imagem);
    }

    if( in != null){
        sc  = new DefaultStreamedContent(in);
    }else{
        sc = null; 
    }
         return sc;
}
```

abaixo a parte do código da página em que utilizo para exibir a imagem

```
<div id="envolveTexto">
                <div id="texto">

                    <p:dataGrid columns="3" value="#{projetistaBean.listaDeProjetistas}" var="projetista" >

                        <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                            <p:graphicImage value="#{projetista.mostrarImagemDeByte()}" width="70" height="70" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{projetista.nome}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:dataGrid>

                </div>
             </div>
```

Era para aparecer um datagrid com as imagens que estão no banco de dados, juntamente com o nome de cada uma delas.

Comment: Não sei qual o contexto da sua aplicação, mas não é uma boa prática gravar imagens direto no banco de dados. Você poderia gravar essas imagens no servidor onde está a aplicação criando uma estrutura de pastas/subpastas se necessário. No banco de dados você guardaria apenas o caminho ou o nome da imagem, num campo varchar comum.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido!!

O graphicImage não funciona se for utilizado dentro de uma tag de conjunto como por exemplo o datagrid se as imagens forem salvas em banco de dados.

Caso precise mostra-las dentro de um datagrid, deve-se salvar as imagens em pastas temporarias dentro do servidor da aplicação e então referencia-las pelo id.

fiz isso e deu certo

Comment: User, na verdade funciona sim, mas precisa de uma construção um tanto quanto inortodoxa. Já caí nessa mesma armadilha antes. O problema aqui é o escopo do *bean* (que deve estar setado como *request*). Como o BalusC explicou [nessa resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage/12452144#12452144) o método que gera a imagem é chamado duas vezes(uma vez para gerar a URL e uma segunda vez quando o browser realmente resolver baixá-la); como isso acontece em dois *requests* subsequentes o escopo é importante.

Comment: Escreva um *managed bean* `@ApplicationScoped` para recuperar as imagens e use a *tag* `<f:param>` para trafegar o `id` do projetista atual para o método que exibirá a imagem (exemplo completo na resposta do BalusC). Dessa foram você garante que o conteúdo da imagem esteja sempre disponível e não depende de nenhum estado do lado da aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de:

```
sc  = new DefaultStreamedContent(in);
```

Tenta:

```
sc  = new DefaultStreamedContent(in, "image/png");
```

É apenas um detalhe, mas muitas vezes esse tipo de detalhe é o "x" da questão.

Outra coisa, mude o nome do método de **mostrarImagemDeByte** para **getMostrarImagemDeByte**.

Comment: Fiz a mudança das duas coisas que você falou, mas infelizmente continua sem aparecer. Estranho que eu tenho outra aplicação utilizando o mesmo processo e funciona.

Comment: E não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro? Nada no console? Nenhuma exceção?

Comment: pior que não.. O problema é que a imagem aparece como se fosse uma imagem sem formato.

Comment: Seu _ManagedBean_ está com qual escopo? Pra funcionar ele precisa estar com **@RequestScoped**.

Comment: Uso SessionScoped, mas este não é o problema. Fiz um teste agora e vi que ele só não está funcionando quando uso dentro de uma lista de dados, como estava usando em um dataGrid. Depois fiz um teste buscando no banco de dados um único elemento da tabela e utilizei a mesma forma para mostrar a imagem e funcionou

Comment: Cara, muito estranho. Eu fiz uma aplicação com JSF + PrimeFaces e em determinada página também uso um dataGrid pra listar imagens que foram salvas pela aplicação. E aqui funciona normal. O único detalhe é que tive que deixar o MB com @RequestScoped pra poder retornar o StreamedContent. Seu p:dataGrid está dentro de um h:form?

Comment: está. É estranho mesmo. Funciona normal, mas não funciona para o datagrid e fiz a mudança para o requestScoped, mas continua na mesma

Comment: as suas imagens eram salvas em banco de dados, ou em pastas na aplicação?

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho mais ideia do que possa ser, mas pra finalizar: no seu XHTML tire os parênteses no **#{projetista.mostrarImagemDeByte()}** e procure deixar o método com o **get** na frente.

Comment: Em pastas no servidor onde está a aplicação. É pouco aconselhável salvar imagens direto no banco de dados.